# How to get minimum value of an expression in two variables without calculus

Tags: linear-algebra

I have an expression given as: \begin{eqnarray*}
6\left(a-b-\frac{1}{3}\right)^2+5\left(b-\frac{4}{5}\right)^2
\end{eqnarray*}

And I want to find the minimum value of this expression. Now I do know calculus and that it will make the process a lot more easier but I was wondering how can it be done without calculus. Probably doesn't make sense to use $AM>= GM$ inequality here. What are the other techniques using which it can be done?
A single variable quadratic would have been easy, but since it's in two variables I can't really think of any method.

Comment: Can you determine the minimum of $6x^2 + 5y^2$? Can you see that it is the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression is non-negative and it has the value $0$ when $a=\frac 1  3+\frac  4 5 , b=\frac  4 5$. So the minimum value is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

$0$ will be the minimum value that expression can take ,since otherwise it will always be positive now solve for $a$,$b$.

Answer (score 0):

Both terms are squared so cannot be negative (assuming you are not considering complex numbers).

The second term depends on $b$ alone. The minimum of this is achieved independently of $a$. Since the minimum of any real square is zero this implies $b-4/5=0$.

With this value of $b$, next consider the first squared term to find the value of $a$ which minimizes it.